# PHP convert array values to keys

Tags: php

Given the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'lorem ipsum'
    [1] => 'dolor sit amet'
    [2] => 'consectetur adipiscing elit'
)
```

What is the best way to convert this to the following:

```
Array
(
    ['lorem ipsum'] => true
    ['dolor sit amet'] => true
    ['consectetur adipiscing elit'] => true
)
```

Other than foreach-ing and creating a new array? Is there any built-in PHP function that can do this for me?

The values of the keys in the new array will always be a fixed value, i.e `true`.

I looked at [array_flip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) but don't think this will allow me to apply a fixed value.

Comment: No no other built-in function. Need to do it through `foreach()`  or combo of some built-in function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As AlivetoDie noted, there's no built in, single call method you could use. But if you simply want to omit `foreach` (and creating intermediary results), the following is a one-line solution:

```
$out = array_combine($in, array_fill(0, count($in), true));
```

https://3v4l.org/YFBkW

or:

```
$out = array_map(function () { return true; }, array_flip($in));
```

if you need more control.

Comment: Given that `1` evaluates as truthy, nice solution!

Comment: `Is there any built-in PHP function that can do this for me?`-> No, the above one is combo of functions.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I understood the *"Other than foreach-ing"* to be of higher relevance.

Comment: @Yoshi  don't worry I didn't criticise you. Your answer is good BTW.+1